# create Android apps to communicate with bluetooth

Tags: performance

I'm ignorant in android software- I want to communicate "Arduino" with mobile and send/resive byte in Bluetooth mode - I want to display this code in several page ,some time convert this byte to certain string and then display it

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the Arduino tutorial? Its really basic but is a working framework to help develop more complex android apps.